# jQuery Dialog, UpdatePanel, RegisterStartupScript, with Show: 'blind' bug?

Tags: asp.net, jquery, webforms, updatepanel, jquery-ui-dialog

Using ASP.NET Web Forms with an UpdatePanel, and using jQueryUI dialogs with a `<asp:Button>` inside.

First, my code looked like [this simple dialog demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net/5j3xn/) with a `show: 'blind'` effect, but I had the issue that jQuery moves the dialog outside the form, preventing the ASPNET controls from posting back to the server. So, I used [this excellent blog solution](http://blog.roonga.com.au/2009/07/using-jquery-ui-dialog-with-aspnet-and.html), namely by adding this to the dialog init:

```
open: function (type, data) {
    $(this).parent().appendTo("form");
},
```

However, this seems to cause a bug in which the dialog loads in the corner of the page before being positioned, [as you can see](http://www.jsfiddle.net/5j3xn/1/) (hit "run" on that page to see the dialog reload). I can fix this by removing the blind effect from the dialog:

```
show: 'blind',
```

Removing the blind effect removes this appear-in-the-corner issue, [as you can see here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/5j3xn/2/). However, I like my blind effect. Is there a way to make it play nicely with the UpdatePanel and this ASP.NET Web Forms `appendTo()` hack?

**EDIT:**

Moving the `$(this).parent().appendTo("form")` command to occur once at pageLoad instead of every time the dialog opens does fix the issue. However, if the dialog is opened with a command from the code-behind like the following, the `div` jumps out of the `form` again:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Me.GetType, "Show", "showDialog();", True)
```

At this point, it looks like a bug with `RegisterStartupScript`! Is there a workaround for injecting JavaScript from the code-behind that doesn't move my dialog's `div`? In this case, I run server-side code to decide if the dialog should be shown, so I can't just use jQuery's `.click()` to bind the dialog to the button. It needs to be conditional based on code-behind calculations.

Comment: What is the showDialog(); function? is this the same as the showMessageSentDialog(); function?

Answer (score 0):

Take

```
$(this).parent().appendTo("form");
```

and place it like this

```
$(function() {
    var dlg = $("#messageSentDialog").dialog({
        bgiframe: true,
        autoOpen: false,
        draggable: false,
        resizable: false,
        modal: true,            
        show: 'blind',
        buttons: {
            Ok: function() {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        }
    });
    dlg.parent().appendTo("form");
});

function showMessageSentDialog() {    
    $("#messageSentDialog").dialog("open");
}

$(function() {
    showMessageSentDialog();
});
```

Fiddled [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5j3xn/7/)

Comment: Your post really confused me, since I had tried that. However, I've now pinpointed the problem. Even though that works on jsFiddle, it doesn't work in my app, because I'm injecting the .dialog() call via ASP.NET's RegisterStartupScript, which moves the div back out of the form. See my edit.